# Multisite login - registration is duplicated

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, multisite

I am running a Multisite installation of Wordpress that runs WooCommerce. There six subsites, three of which are a traditional B2C retail and another three that are B2B Wholesale. Anybody can access the B2C (they are territory dependent), create an account and transact. The B2B is different; we manually create the accounts for our Wholesale customers.

- **B2C** - [www.domain.com/my-account](http://www.domain.com/my-account)
- **B2B** - [www.domain.com/wholesale/my-account](http://www.domain.com/wholesale/my-account)

So we have have noticed that if the Wholesale customer goes to the B2C my account page mistakingly and uses their B2B credentials then they are logged in and a new registration is created there. SO they now have access to both the B2B and B2C sites which can lead to confusion.

How I can prevent this auto 'dual' login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default WordPress Multisite indeed has a shared user base. So, there is no new registration created in de B2B site. It is simply the same registration for all six sites.

Of course, this can be modified. You could try programming this yourself, but there are plenty plugins that will do this for you. We don't do software recommendations around here, but you could try googling for "wordpress multisite user management plugin".

Comment: Thanks @cjbj. After asking Google the right question I found this solution (https://really-simple-plugins.com/prevent-cross-site-authentication-for-logged-in-users-on-wordpress-multisite/) which uses a non-plugin approach (which I prefer) that uses an action. I have yet to try but it looks like it will do the job.